# OxyPlot - Editing title directly on plot

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I am currently working on an application that uses OxyPlot to display plots. To enhance it, I want to be able to edit the plot title by clicking on it.

I would like to know if this feature is already available in OxyPlot, but disabled by default. The OxyPlot documentation is not complete and lacks a section for titles.

Comment: I suggest to read [tour] and update your question according guidelines

Comment: yeah, you can do it, why not?

Comment: @FoggyFinder I know I can do it on my own, but I would like to know if it's already implemented in OxyPlot, instead of doing all the work and then realize it is implemented.